# How to access Photos library from Monterey on OS X 10.6.8?

Tags: photos, snow-leopard, monterey

I have a bunch of videos saved in Photos which was running on a OS Monterey 12.6.6. I have an older MacBook that is running 10.6.8. It has iPhoto but that does not recognize the Photos library. What are my options in accessing and exporting the videos individually?

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of Photos/iPhoto usually can't read libraries created/updated by newer versions.

You can access photos/videos directly via Finder though:

- Open the Pictures folder,
- right-click on the Photos library and select "Show Package Contents",
- look for you photos/videos, either in the yearly directories, in `Masters` or (the cumbersome way) in `originals`.